# Error while using SOIL library in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I get the following error ":-1: error: cannot find -llibSOIL" when trying to add SOIL. Here are the steps I am doing:

1) Add the following to .pro file

```
SOILPATH = "/home/swayu/Desktop/color quantization/Simple OpenGL Image Library"
INCLUDEPATH += "$${SOILPATH}/src"
LIBS += -L"$$(SOILPATH)/lib" -llibSOIL
```

*libSOIL.a file resides in the lib folder but still I am getting the above error.

2) include soil.h in the cpp file where I want to use the functionality offered by this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
LIBS += "-L$${SOILPATH}/lib" -llibSOIL
```

rather than:

```
LIBS += -L"$$(SOILPATH)/lib" -llibSOIL
```

According to [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs), that's the right syntax (quotes are inclusing `-L` and use curly braces for the path variable "SOILPATH").

Comment: that didn't make any difference. Is there any possibility that I may have to include the any of soil's folder in the qt directory?

Comment: Did you try. 1 to replace spaces by _ in library path (spaces may cause problems)? 2 replace -llibSOIL by -llibSOIL.a? 3 replace $$(SOILPATH) by the actual path (there could be a problem with variable resolution)?

Comment: LIBS += -L/home/swati/Desktop/color\ quantization/Simple\ OpenGL\ Image\ Library/lib -lSOIL

Comment: BTW did you notice that you are using '{SOILPATH}' for 'INCLUDEPATH' but '(SOILPATH)' for 'LIBS'. Are they equivalent?

Comment: It must be possible to preserve your SOILPATH variable and reference it on the LIB line. If you manage to do that, could you edit my answer with the correct final syntax and then approve it?

Comment: -L"$${SOILPATH}/lib" -lSOIL also worked :) now implies '{SOILPATH}' is not the same  as'(SOILPATH)'. This was the mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit+approve the answer.

Comment: Good collaborative answer!